# app-fastopt.js no longer properly added to resources after upgrading

Tags: scala.js, scala-2.12

I have been updating a project to scala 2.12, and one of my last remaining problems is that the fastOptJS task no longer seems to be providing the recompiled scala.js files to the new build.

I have the following lines in my build.sbt file:

```
lazy val appJVM = app.jvm
  .settings(
    (resources in Compile) ++= Seq(
      (fastOptJS in (appJS, Compile)).value.data,
      (packageJSDependencies in (appJS, Compile)).value
    )
  )
```

That used to do the task, but after updating to 2.12 my assets/app-fastopt.js file does not change despite running the fastOptJS task in every way I know how. The updated fastopt.js file DOES appear in the app/js/target/scala-2.12 subdirectory.

I am using version 0.6.25 of the scala.js plugin, on scala 2.12.6 and sbt 1.1.6

Answer (score 0):

*pacepalm*

Please disregard. The browser was caching old versions.